# Import instrument libraries into GarageBand after 10.3.2?

Tags: software, instruments, garage-band

As of version 10.3.2, GarageBand appears to have lost the ability to import other instruments or libraries.  Is there a way to import third party instruments into GarageBand in 10.3?

Along those lines, where are some good options for additional instrument voices for GarageBand?  Apple removed the option to purchase sound/instrument libraries.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25047?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) from August of 2019 states that GarageBand supports audio unit plugins.

So you still should be able to "import" third party instruments.  Maybe it just needs to be pointed at your directory of plugins.

Here's [another link](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph24994?locale=en_US) from Apple regarding re-downloading available sounds ( maybe the upgrade nuked the old ones? ).

Answer (score 0):

If you previously purchased GarageBand 6, it will be available for download in the App Store; the two versions can both live on the same machine just fine.

Comment: Understood, but not entirely helpful as I'm working within GarageBand 10.3 and would like to add more instrumentation in that environment, not an older version.